# VBA - Input box - userform

Tags: excel, inputbox, vba

This is my code:

```
qty = InputBox("Please enter the quantity to be added.", "Add Quantity")
Cells(row, 2) = qty
Description = InputBox("Please enter a description.", "Enter Description")
Cells(row, 3) = Description
Unitp = InputBox("Please enter a unit price.", "Enter UnitPrice")
Cells(row, 4) = Unitp
Amount = InputBox("Please enter an amount.", "Enter Amount")
Cells(row, 5) = Amount
```

`Qty` & `Unitp` is getting displayed correctly in Excel. However, when I enter characters in the `Description` input box then it throws an error. But if I enter `no`. it goes through but displays as `FALSE` in the Excel cell. This is the case for both `Descripton` & `Amount`.

Can someone help?

Comment: How is `Description` defined?

Comment: Did you write `Dim Description As Bool` or so?

Answer (score 1):

You need to Declare your variables for them to take the correct input, put this above your code:

```
Dim qty as Integer
Dim Unitp as Double
Dim Description as String
Dim Amount as Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

this issue is resolved. I had declared description for some other variable. Just changed it form Description to Desc & like wise for Amount fields.

Worked just fine.

Thanks for your help guys!